# Call Cloud Function from another Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've searched a way to call a cloud function inside another cloud function but none of them succeed. I have to paid for it or there is one way to do it ?

I've also try using fetch but also didnt work

I have a Cloud function of payments

```
exports.payments= functions.https.onCall((data,context) {
//Code
}
```

My second functions is as following and receives a list of users and the amount of money that we have to pay them

```
exports.payUsers= functions.https.onCall((data,context) {
//Code
}
```

The idea is that in the second function depending on some conditions we have to call the first functions if its all ok

Comment: Please share code.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do.  What kind of functions are you writing?  What are you hoping to accomplish?  What exactly have you tried that didn't work the way you expect?

Comment: In general it seems like an unusual approach to be nesting calls to Cloud Functions. If they're all written in the same language (since you tagged with `node.js`), you might as well just have one JavaScript function call the other. For an example of this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340326/firestore-cloud-functions-priority/50340352#50340352

Comment: The error I had trying to call another functions was the following "reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND". I ve research and was a problem of that is not for free. @DougStevenson

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried it and it works, The only thing that is not so nice is that I had to duplicate code because in the function of js I had to put all the code of the first cloud function.

Comment: I don't think there's any other solution at the moment. Typically you can minimize duplication by isolating the regular JavaScript code into separate files, and only have the Cloud Functions bits in `index.js`.

Comment: Well, thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, I will go with that approach I think.

Comment: Can you bring in pub sub in between? Publish a static message to a pubsub topic and make the other cloud function a subscriber to the same topic. That way you can trigger the cloud function from your current function.