# How to call firebase https function B from https function A, without using axios or fetch?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have two different https functions:

1. functions: verifyCreds: http://localhost:5000/us-central1/verifyCreds
2. functions: accountInfo: http://localhost:5000/us-central1/accountInfo

I want to call **'verifyCreds'** from **'accountInfo'** , without using axios or fetch.

Is there any way of calling the function internally without using axios or fetch method, as we do `functions.config()` to get environment variables.

Comment: You'll typically want to just use regular function calls here, instead of Cloud Functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784000/calling-a-cloud-function-from-another-cloud-function, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340326/firestore-cloud-functions-priority

Comment: They both are two different https functions and in my scenario I don't want it to write them in same function.

Comment: What makes the approach recommended by experienced Cloud Functions developers in this linked answers not applicable to your situation?