# google function calling another google function: statusCodeError 500

Tags: google-cloud-functions, request-promise

I have a google function which calls a API running on another google function. Both functions are in NodeJS. I am using `request-promise-native` for calling the second function.

The code is as follows:

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');
const URL = '....';

const callAPI = (param1, param2) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const url = URL;
    const data = {'param1': param1, 'param2':param2};
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: url,
      body: data,
      json: true
    };
    rp(options)
      .then(result => {
        resolve(result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('error in apicall:', err);
        resolve('');
      });
  });
};

callAPI('p1', 'p2')
.then(result => {
  ... do something
})
.catch(err => {
  ... handle error
});
```

One in a while I get a statusCodeError (which is caught in the request-promise catch) as below

```
{ StatusCodeError: 500 - "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<m ....
```

There is no consistency on when it occurs, but it does occur at some frequency.

Comment: If the other code is also a Google Cloud Function, I highly recommend just calling the actual code instead of going through the GCF infrastructure (and incurring double billing).

Comment: Which billing plan is your project on?  Are you paying for this project?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: what do you mean by "just calling the actual code"?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson: The project is under the normal Google Account Billing, where I am charged (credit card) every month. And the Firebase is under the Blaze plan. I must clarify that the calls from one function to the other **do work**. It is just that once in a way I get the above error

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340326/firestore-cloud-functions-priority

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for the link. Will the method you are suggesting work across projects? In my use-case, function 1 is in a client's project and function 2 is (like an API call) in a different project

Comment: This approach has *nothing* to do with Cloud Functions infrastructure, but everything to do with code re-use. If you ensure the code for the (non GCF) functionality that you want to use in two Cloud Functions, it doesn't matter what GCP project each is in.